# Cannot map data correctlly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, mapping

I'm new to React.js development and need help with this issue. I created a service using FastAPI, which executes a number of SQL SELECT declarations against an Oracle database, takes the results, and exposes them as a REST API using JSON data format.

In a Chrome Web-browser, I see this information when I execute a `GET` to the API:
[API GET results][1]

Therefore, the API is returning results correctly. To show them all in my React app, I created this component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    loading: true,
    pedidos: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:8000/pedidos-bloqueados/";
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(d => {
      this.setState({ pedidos: [d], loading: false });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.loading? <div>Carregando...</div> : <div><li> Cliente: * {(this.state.pedidos.map((pedido, index)=>(this.state.pedidos[index]))).map((p, i)=> p['cliente'])}</li></div> } *
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It turns out that, when a ***map()*** function inside ***render()*** method gets executed, the only information shown is:

`Cliente:`

Without any more data. And the component is not allowed to do a ***for()*** loop inside ***render()*** method, what could, possibly, render the objects encoded in the JSON list.

I think the problem is in the snippet:
 `{ this.state.loading? <div>Loading...</div> : <div><li> Cliente:  {(this.state.pedidos.map((pedido, index)=>(this.state.pedidos[index]))).map((p, i)=> p['cliente'])}</li></div> }`

How should I change my code to show the properties of each object in the list when rendering the component? (*Note*: **cliente** is ***just one of the JSON object attributes - there are others like vendedor, pedido, and so on... But, if I manage to list this field, I can replicate the behavior to the others).

I thank you **VERY MUCH** for any assistance with this matter!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHuN3.png

Comment: Could you show us what console.log(this.state.pedidos) returns on the whole? Or you have a snippet to look at?

Comment: @ale917k , thaks for the quick response. The console shows the same data from the attached image: [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHuN3.png) .

Comment: I think the problem is the way you are mapping through those data - Try with the following: ```{ this.state.pedidos.map(pedido => pedido.cliente) }``` - So with this you are practically iterating through each object in the array, and out of each object we returns the "cliente" property.. Let me know if that works so I'll write a proper answer for it

Comment: I did as instructed, but, unfortunatelly, now I'm getting an "Property 'cliente' does not exist on type 'never'" error. Please, let me know your considerations about this error.